# Conserving memory/programming efficiently when using `std::shared_ptr`

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory, smart-pointers

I am trying to create a bunch of shared pointers and put them into various containers.

Using raw pointers I would think to do the following:

```
Container a, b, c;
MyClass *ptr;
while(!finishedCreating){
    ptr = new MyClass(SOME_CHANGING_THING);
    a.add(ptr);
    b.add(ptr);
    c.add(ptr);
}
```

But of course now if I want to destruct `a`, `b`, and `c` I would need to delete the pointers that they contain. If I did the following:

```
~Container{
    delete[] myListOfPointers;
}
```

I would get an error when destructing because deleting `a` would delete the same memory that `b` and `c` are supposed to get rid of.

Enter smart pointers, specifically, `std::shared_ptr`. I would like to do something similar to before where I can create a single entity and use it to point to tons of memory locations but I'm not sure how to do this?

Would I want to create a pointer to a `std::shared_ptr` so that I can reallocate that pointer such as

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> *ptr = new std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(THING));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shared_ptr` are here to allocate memory for you... Do not use `new` with them !

The basic usage would be:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr(new MyClass(THING));
```

But even better:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>(THING);
```

The latter provide a lot more guarantee over exception handling and also ensure you won't use `new` anymore.

Your container will now be something like:

```
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> Container;
```

For more information read [shared_ptr on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).